# create-react-app included in Azure-Samples / todo-csharp-sql-swa-func does not auto refresh when making tsx changes

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

The new azure developer cli template (todo-csharp-sql-swa-func), doesn't seem to rebuild when making changes to tsx files.  Is my assumption correct that the typescript files are supposed to compile upon saving and then propagate to the localhost server and then refresh in the browser?